# How to use a variable in Actions.SCENE_KEY (react native router flux)

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

Forgive me if this is something simple i'm overlooking. I'm fairly new to programming, much newer to React and React Native.

I'm building a simple navigation drawer.

The drawer displays a Menu component which has a `renderMenuItem(item)` function which returns the following.

```
<Button onPress={() => this._onItemSelect(item)} style={styles.navItem} >{item}</Button>
```

It's responsible for returning the correctly labeled button to the render function.

The problem I'm having is when it gets to the `onItemSelect` funtion,

```
_onItemSelect(item) {
    //  handle action to render the new page!

    Actions.item      // Won't work
    //Actions.Page2     // Hardcoding the scene here won't work either
    );
```

I can't get it to actually display the new scene when the button is pressed. If I were to hardcode the scene into the `onPress()` function in the button, I can get it to work. For example:

```
<Button onPress={Actions.Page2} style={styles.navItem} >{item}</Button>
```

Obviously, that won't work. What I need is to be able to use **item** in either of the functions, the `renderMenuItem(item)` funtion or the `onItemSelect(item)` function.

Thank you. I've been wrecking my brain since last night trying to figure this one out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Actions.SCENE_KEY` is a function that you can call, and when doing so the navigator will perform the action. It works when you do `<Button onPress={Actions.Page2}` because the button takes a function reference as the `onPress` property and it calls it for you when appropriate. You just have to change your code to:

```
_onItemSelect(item) {
    //  handle action to render the new page!

    Actions.Page2();
);
```

Also, since you depend on the value of `item`, you can pass it as a prop, to the component, like this:

```
_onItemSelect(item) {
    //  handle action to render the new page!

    Actions.Page2({item: item});
);
```

Then, your next screen will receive the usual props plus a new one called `item` with the value that you passed.

Comment: While this did not resolve my concern completely, it did lead me down the right path. What I wanted was a way to use item(which holds a name of the button pressed)  as the action. (ex: `Actions.item()`) That did not work. however, I simply used a switch statement in the _onItemSelect function. 


`onItemSelect(item) {
     switch(item){
      case "page one":
        Actions.PageOne();
        break;
      case "page two":
        Actions.PageTwo();
        break;
}`

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 7):

A bit late for you but may be it help others.

use bracket notation to call functions dynamically

```
_onItemSelect(item) {
    Actions[item]();
);
```

variable `item` should be the key from your routes/scenes.

Comment: This is very helpful. In the docs it says, Actions[key].call() It doesn't work if you do following. Actions[key].call({props:object}).
Only works for Actions[key]({props:object})